# Search excerpt with Search API (rendered HTML)

Tags: search, views

Is it possible to create a search excerpt from the Entity HTML Output (with Search API)?

What I did:

1. Activated highlighting and "create excerpt" within my Search index. Added "complete entity view" for the whole HTML content:
   [image]
2. Activated the new "Entity HTML Output" field als Fulltext:
   [image]
3. Within my search view, I added "excerpt" as a field.

But the excerpt does not show for the Entity HTML Output. Is there something wrong with my confi?

Comment: It is a missing feature in Search API module and i have created a issue over here https://www.drupal.org/node/2579141 (it has a patch that is supposed to solve it, needs review as of now).